# Bind Key to a button C# WFA?

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-shortcuts

Whenever button is clicked, key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> should be pressed.

I found solution of the reverse process everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:  `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("^{F1}");`

[Full MSDN SendKeys documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx)